# Create QML Widget with a picture in Attributes Form

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style, qml

I would like a Qmlwidget in the Attributes Form to show a picture.
So far I have created the basic qml for a blue rectangle:

```py
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "steelblue"
    Text{ text: "A rectangle" }

}
```

I'd like to replace the Rectangle dictionnary by a Picture dictionnary with the picture path generated from project folder path and an attribute.

*maybe* something looking like that?:

```py
Image {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source: "expression.evaluate("concat(@project_folder,
                                      '/Photos/', 
                                      attribute( $currentfeature, 'name'),
                                      '_1.jpg')"
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put the content of what you have put into "source" at the moment into the "text" of your first example? Try doing that and make the path work first this way.

Comment: I tried to replace with Text { text: ".../Image.jpg"}, Text { source: ".../Image.jpg"} ,Image { text: ".../Image.jpg"} and Image { source: ".../Image.jpg"} but no success even with a simple image path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1

Check the calculated path instead of the final image

This is a combination of the two examples you posted.
What exactly is the output you get?

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "steelblue"
    Text{
        text: "expression.evaluate("concat(@project_folder,
                                      '/Photos/', 
                                      attribute( $currentfeature, 'name'),
                                      '_1.jpg')"
    }

}
```

## Step 2

Fix the path

My first bet goes towards removing the `"` around the expression and verify

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "steelblue"
    Text{
        text: expression.evaluate("concat(@project_folder,
                                      '/Photos/', 
                                      attribute( $currentfeature, 'name'),
                                      '_1.jpg')")
    }
}
```

## Step 3

Use it in an `Image` again

```
Image {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source:  expression.evaluate("concat(@project_folder,
                                      '/Photos/', 
                                      attribute( $currentfeature, 'name'),
                                      '_1.jpg')")
}
```

## Step 4

Iron out any issues with `\` escaping

```
Image {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source:  expression.evaluate("concat(replace(replace(
             @project_folder,'\\\\','/'),'C:',''),'/Photos/',
             attribute( $currentfeature, 'name'), '_1')")
}
```

Comment: moving the " does create a text in the rectangle with the correct path but doesn't insert the picture. here's a capture: [link](https://imgur.com/a/P86KSem)

Comment: Very good, so step number 1 is good: we actually have *fixed* the path.
Step 2 -> reintegrate into your original proposal

Comment: it only creates a white square (like in the previous capture but white and without text) same when opening a point's attributes.

Comment: Can you try the same `Image` with a hardcoded path? (i.e. without any expression etc)

Comment: `Image{source: "C:\picture.jpg" }` also creates a white square

Comment: It works with `Image{source: "///picture.jpg" }` the new problem is to replace '\' with / in @project_folder,  `expression.evaluate("replace( @project_folder,'\\','/')` doesn't work

Comment: with the change to  **expression.evaluate("concat(replace(replace( @project_folder,'\\\\','/'),'C:',''),'/Photos/',attribute( $currentfeature, 'name'), '_1')")** it works. '\' had to be escaped twice in the expression. Thank you for your help

Comment: what to do if image is stored as blob in the layer field